# How to search all instance for regex value in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I work in a secure environment and need a way of running a script against our SQL instances i.e. all dbs, tables etc. to search for the use of certain values and to show where they are... is there any way of doing this?  I've scoured the net but can't seem to find this!

I've put together this script with help from various sources (vyaskn) but need help in expanding the code to include db's and regex functionality. I just don't have enough experience in using the system views and dynamic SQL to do it myself. It's more important that I get the regex stuff working if searching through all dbs is more difficult.

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled',1
reconfigure

DECLARE @SearchStr NVARCHAR(100)

-- search for uk phone number for example   
SET @SearchStr = '(((\+44)? ?(\(0\))? ?)|(0))( ?[0-9]{3,4}){3}'

CREATE TABLE #Results
    (
      ColumnName NVARCHAR(370) ,
      ColumnValue NVARCHAR(3630)
    )

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(256) ,
    @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128) ,
    @SearchStr2 NVARCHAR(110)
SET @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%', '''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = ''
        SET @TableName = ( SELECT   MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'
                                        + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
                           FROM     INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                           WHERE    TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
                                    AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.'
                                    + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
                                    AND OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA)
                                                              + '.'
                                                              + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)),
                                                       'IsMSShipped') = 0
                         )


        WHILE ( @TableName IS NOT NULL )
            AND ( @ColumnName IS NOT NULL ) 
            BEGIN

                SET @ColumnName = ( SELECT  MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
                                    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                                    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName,
                                                              2)
                                            AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName,
                                                              1)
                                            AND DATA_TYPE IN ( 'char',
                                                              'varchar',
                                                              'nchar',
                                                              'nvarchar',
                                                              'int', 'decimal' )
                                            AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                                  )



                IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
                    BEGIN

                        INSERT  INTO #Results
                                EXEC
                                    ( 'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.'
                                      + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT('
                                      + @ColumnName + ', 3630) FROM '
                                      + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' + ' WHERE '
                                      + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
                                    )

                    END

            END   

    END



SELECT  ColumnName ,
        ColumnValue
FROM    #Results



DROP TABLE #Results

--sp_configure 'clr enabled',0
--reconfigure
```

Comment: that would be a neat script to see, but I'm not doing all that work for 50 points.  build some nested loops over `sys.databases`, `sys.objects`, and `sys.columns` that generate some dynamic SQL that will utilize your [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254498%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) [regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx) implementation.

Comment: i was thinking of building some stuff around the system stored procs but i don't have much experience in using them...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find all available SQL instance within the particular network. You can checkout this [example for sample code](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/locate_sql_servers.aspx). Once you receive the information about all SQL instances, such as server name, instance name, version, and databases. Now you must have id and password to connect with each database to retrieve any information from any Table present any database. Next create connection with each database and do required search operation.

You can take help of [Full-Text Indexing](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/understanding-full-text-indexing-in-sql-server/) while searching a particular regular expression.

Comment: we only have a small setup and i know that we only have one instance of sql per server, so would only need to run the script within SQL for each server...

Comment: i am the dba so could run under my account

Comment: "I know that we only have one instance of sql per server"-- Well that means you know the server information and the required information to connect with each SQL server instances. In this case you need to write some code. Without writing code its not possible. As you will do a common task(search operation) in all sql instances you can write a common SQL statements for searching your required values for all available SQL instances. Try writing a small application and then connect with SQL instances one by one and run the common script for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using one of the tools from [EMS](http://www.sqlmanager.net/) to do a regex replace on an Oracle DB schema. By now, I forget which tool I used, but I was able to export the schema to an SQL file and manipulate it as plain text.

You might want to try out the [SQL Manager](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/manager) and the [DB Extract](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/dbextract) products. They both have free trials, and both support a wide range of databases.

Once you get your schema, data, and stored procedures into a single SQL file, running a search should be no problem.